# AutoHotkey: Dynamic resize control based on text

Tags: controls, autohotkey, autosize

Consider the following snippet:

```
FormatTime, time,
Gui, Add, Text, vcTime, 
GuiControl, , cTime, % time 
Gui, Show, NoActivate Center AutoSize
```

`AutoSize` is based on the initial value from `Gui, Add, Text, vcTime` and not on the new value set by `GuiControl, , cTime, % time`. Depending on months etc., `%time%` length can vary. How can I automatically resize the window to adapt to updated values of `%time%`?
 `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`AutoSize` is actually based on the current control sizes when `Gui Show` is called](https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/blob/7aaba1e190464400e587774b5b8058fd12416af6/source/script_gui.cpp#L6722). The issue is that the "blank" subcommand to `GuiControl` for text controls [does not automatically resize the control](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControl.htm#Text); it just changes the text and you still have to call `GuiControl Move` with a new size yourself. So, in your example, if you replace `AutoSize` with `w200` the text will still be cut off at the same point.

As far as I know, there's not really a "built-in" automatic way to resize the text control based on the new text. The closest way is to use AHK's initial size calculation when creating a text control: create a new text control with the desired text, use `GuiControlGet` to get the size of the new control, and finally set the size of the original control to that size using `GuiControl Move`. Here's an example function which does this, adapted from [here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/16414-hexview-31-for-stdlib/page-2#entry108223):

```
SetTextAndResize(controlHwnd, newText, fontOptions := "", fontName := "") {
    Gui 9:Font, %fontOptions%, %fontName%
    Gui 9:Add, Text, R1, %newText%
    GuiControlGet T, 9:Pos, Static1
    Gui 9:Destroy

    GuiControl,, %controlHwnd%, %newText%
    GuiControl Move, %controlHwnd%, % "h" TH " w" TW
}
```

Which would fit into your example like so:

```
FormatTime, time,
Gui, Add, Text, HwndTimeHwnd vcTime,
SetTextAndResize(TimeHwnd, time)
Gui, Show, NoActivate Center AutoSize
```

Now whenever you use `SetTextAndResize` instead of just setting the text you can use `Gui Show, AutoSize` to automatically resize the window correctly. Note that if you changed the font with `Gui Font` before adding the text control you would have to pass those same options to `SetTextAndResize`.

Alternatively, I looked at how AHK itself calculates the initial size of a text control for `Gui Add, Text` when none is provided and found it uses the Windows API function [`DrawText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) with `DT_CALCRECT`. Here's another implementation of `SetTextAndResize` I wrote using this directly:

```
SetTextAndResize(controlHwnd, newText) {
    dc := DllCall("GetDC", "Ptr", controlHwnd)

    ; 0x31 = WM_GETFONT
    SendMessage 0x31,,,, ahk_id %controlHwnd%
    hFont := ErrorLevel
    oldFont := 0
    if (hFont != "FAIL")
        oldFont := DllCall("SelectObject", "Ptr", dc, "Ptr", hFont)

    VarSetCapacity(rect, 16, 0)
    ; 0x440 = DT_CALCRECT | DT_EXPANDTABS
    h := DllCall("DrawText", "Ptr", dc, "Ptr", &newText, "Int", -1, "Ptr", &rect, "UInt", 0x440)
    ; width = rect.right - rect.left
    w := NumGet(rect, 8, "Int") - NumGet(rect, 0, "Int")

    if oldFont
        DllCall("SelectObject", "Ptr", dc, "Ptr", oldFont)
    DllCall("ReleaseDC", "Ptr", controlHwnd, "Ptr", dc)

    GuiControl,, %controlHwnd%, %newText%
    GuiControl Move, %controlHwnd%, % "h" h " w" w
}
```

I'm not sure how it compares to the first method in terms of performance, but one advantage is that it gets the font based on the control itself rather than having to provide it to the function yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I tried only the first and works like a charm. I still have the problem of excessive space around the text. I opened a [new issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49364373/1851270) for that.

Comment: No problem. I'll take a look at that one too.