# Autohotkey: Remove window border

Tags: window, autohotkey, borderless

I would like to display just some text with a background. Despite my attempts, there is a lot of empty space around the text.

```
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop -Border -SysMenu  -Caption 
Gui, Add, Text, , Some text
Gui, Show, AutoSize
WinSet, Style, -0xC00000,     A 
WinSet, Style, -0x40000,      A 
WinSet, ExStyle, -0x00000200, A
```

If, instead of `AutoSize`, I manually set the size, the text is cut.

Comment: Deleted my answer since I missed the part of still wanting a background. I found a way to get no background if you are interested.

Comment: @ZackTarr: yes, it is still interesting post it, please

Comment: Added it back. I didnt want to lose some rep for missing the point. Sadly I havent found anything in terms of lessing the border around the text like you would like. But I will say the transparent window from the code below is being saved for a rainy day on my side! Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a border to the text, i.e.,

```
Gui Add, Text, Border, Some text
```

you'll see it is indeed the window itself with the extra space and not the text control. By default, if no margin is given to a GUI before a control is added it [chooses one that is proportional to the font](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Margin). So, just set the margin to zero before you add the text control:

```
Gui Margin, 0, 0
Gui Add, Text,, Some text
```

Answer (score 1):

This is close to what you are looking for but not the same. This code will change the BG Color to transparent leaving only the text. Figured it would be worth showing off here for future users.

This example is using the CustomColor as a color to turn into the transparent field.

```
CustomColor = EEAA99  
Gui, +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +ToolWindow
Gui, Font, s32
Gui, Add, Text, , Some text 
Gui, Color, %CustomColor%
WinSet, TransColor, %CustomColor% 1000
Gui, Show, AutoSize,NoActivate
```